# Navigation bar overs top portion of my view

Tags: iphone, image, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have an application with a tab bar controller and a navigation controller. In one of the child content views of the navigation controller, I have a image view at the top and some buttons at the bottom. The problem is that the navigation bar obscures the top portion of the image view. My content view is loaded from a NIB file and the image is set at run time. The strange thing is, in another child view I have a table view and that appears correctly.

Comment: can you please post your code that instantiates the image and adds it to the view?

Comment: I have a UIImageView outlet in my view controller and set the image. The imageview is in the XIB at the top of the view with origin at origin of the containing view.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your your autoresizingMask is set properly on your view (see autosizing settings in size inspector, CMD+3).
[UINavigationController overview at iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW28) says:

> Note: Because the amount of space
>   available for the custom view can vary
>   (depending on the size of the other
>   navigation views), your custom view’s
>   autoresizingMask property should be
>   set to have a flexible width and
>   height. Before displaying your view,
>   the navigation controller
>   automatically positions and sizes it
>   to fit the available space.

Then, make sure that the autosizing settings on your imageview is not set to flexible height.

What might be happening is:

1. UINavigationController resizes your view from nib file (shrinks the height).
2. UIImageView in your view is scaled down because the parent view was resized, which makes it look like it's clipped.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have set the content view too large? In InterfaceBuilder, you can enable a placeholder tabbar + navigationbar in cmd+1 of your view. That way you can design it to fit exactly. Alternatively you can fix the size of the content frame unter cmd+3 in IB.